# Fermi-Energy for different cases

Tags: thermodynamics, special-relativity, statistical-mechanics, dispersion, fermi-energy

I Have been working on the fermi energy recently and understand where the fermi-energy equation comes from for the non-relativistic case but does the fermi energy change for the relativistic and ultra-relativistic cases?
I know that each has their own initial energy,
$$E=\frac{p^2}{2m}, \space   E=pc=\hbar kc, \space E=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4} $$
for non-relativistic, relativistic, and ultrarelativistic respectively, how does this affect the fermi-energy say for a gas in these cases?

Answer (score 0):

The way you are asking this question makes it very clear that you do not understand what is being done.

Yes, the simple original expression is only for non-relativistic, and if relativistic corrections start to become important, then there is a slight modification that will take that into account. However, it does not appear in the way that you think it will appear as. It is necessary to take the whole thing into account, not an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

There are some references showing how to derive the Fermi energy for this relativistic linear dispersion : [Relativistic Fermi gas](https://bingweb.binghamton.edu/%7Esuzuki/ThermoStatFIles/11.3%20FD%20Relativistic%20Fermi%20gas-I.pdf)

The ultra-relativistic case (photon-like) is not really realistic but has this simple expression $E_F = \hbar c (3\pi^2n)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ compared to the non-relativistic expression : $E_F = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e} (3\pi^2 n)^{\frac{2}{3}}$.

A material tends to this relativistic expression for an effective massless particle $\frac{m^*}{m_e} \rightarrow 0 $ : graphene is a simple case.